# Convert from string to double removes trailing zeros

Tags: java, double, number-formatting

I am trying to convert a list of doubles from a string format into a double format. I did this by putting them into a list and using the `Double.parseDouble(string)` method.

This works for most numbers but it gives an unwanted output when the double contains a trailing zero the `parseDouble` method is removing it. I don't want this to be removed.

```
String[] values = {"124.50", "45.801", "-15.210"};
List<Double> nums = new ArrayList<Double>();

for(String s: values)
nums.add(Double.parseDouble(s));
Collections.sort(nums);

for(Double d: nums){
    System.out.print(d + " ");
}
```

This yields the output:

```
-15.21 45.801 124.5
```

But I want the trailing zeros. The problem with using a formatted line is that I would have to specify the floating point accuracy that I want when printing values, but I don't have any specific desire to make the numbers accurate to a certain point, merely leave the zeros alone if they are there.

Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "trailing zero" when talking about an actual double value.

Comment: Dang, @BrianRoach beat me to it. There are solutions to your problem but they aren't straight forward @leigero. If you want the output to always have `n` decimal digits, you can use `DoubleFormat`

Comment: Interesting. I don't want a set number of n digits. I guess I'll have to check the String before conversion and add the zero's back manually? That seems very redundant.

Comment: @leigero Yes you can do it like this DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

Comment: @leigero - to be clear, it's the same thing as asking how you would preserve "leading zeros" with an integer (e.g. 01) ... you're conflating the textual representation of a number with the actual binary value

Comment: Thanks @BrianRoach I'll have to approach this task from a totally different angle it seems. What you're saying makes good sense.

Comment: A full answer would take some time, but the gist of it involves creating a wrapper class that holds a `double` value and the number of trailing zeroes. That said ... you may still run into precision issues depending on the original strings. Just holding a ref to the orig string may suit your needs though, depending on what you're doing. (Edit: Ha, and there you go, someone posted that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could store a reference to the original string and print that instead of the parsed double

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] values = {"124.50", "45.801", "-15.210"};
    List<MyDouble> nums = new ArrayList<MyDouble>();

    for(String s: values)
    nums.add(new MyDouble(s));
    Collections.sort(nums);

    for(MyDouble d: nums){
        System.out.print(d + " ");
    }
}

static class MyDouble implements Comparable<MyDouble> {
    final double val;
    final String string;
    MyDouble(String str) {
        string = str;
        val = Double.parseDouble(str);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyDouble o) {
        return (int) (val - o.val);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
-15.210 45.801 124.50
```

Comment: If your array is visible to many other classes and you don't want them dependent on MyDouble, you could make MyDouble a subclass of `java.lang.Number` and specify an array of `Number` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `BigDecimal` to handle the values.  `BigDecimal` preserves trailing zeroes.

```
String[] values = {"124.50", "45.801", "-15.210"};
List<BigDecimal> nums = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();

for(String s: values)
    nums.add(new BigDecimal(s));
Collections.sort(nums);

for(BigDecimal d: nums) {
    System.out.print(d + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want `n` decimal digits, you can do the following:

```
final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
for (Double d : nums) {
    System.out.print(df.format(d) + " ");
}
```

More specifically, this solution works for you but as @BrianRoach mentioned in his comment, there is no such thing as a trailing zero when talking about actual double numbers.

```
final String[] values = {"124.50", "45.801", "-15.210"};
final List<Double> nums = new ArrayList<>();
final List<Double> bkpNums = new ArrayList<>();

for (final String s : values) {
    double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
    nums.add(d);
    bkpNums.add(d);
}
Collections.sort(nums);

for (Double d : nums) {
    System.out.print(values[bkpNums.indexOf(d)] + " ");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fit OPs description: _I don't have any specific desire to make the numbers accurate to a certain point, merely leave the zeros alone if they are there_.

Comment: @Keppil The second (complete) solution actually prints the value from the `values` array that was the "input" and fits the requirement perfectly.

Not sure who neg-voted my solution but I certainly hope they would read my solution completely before down voting. :(

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
```

while printing numbers